# Possible to auto-login or auto-submit a form upon a page loading?

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to determine if it's possible to automatically login or submit a form on page load using javascript or html  ?

Can a link be constructed in such a way that it will go to the destination and automatically attempt login or form submit?  Not trying to pre-fill with any credentials.

Any help is appreciated...thanks!

Comment: Certainly. Just add an `onload` handler that finds the form and submits it. (If you've tried this, and are encountering a specific problem, then you need to provide more details. We can't guess what went wrong.)

Comment: I have yet to try this, wanted to make sure it was possible.  Next step is to code it :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible using `body.onload` event and `document.forms["your-form-id"].submit();`

Comment: Can this work for 3rd party forms/destinations as well?  if www.foo.com has a login page...can I create a link that would auto-login once that destination loads?

Comment: That depends on the page you're connecting to: if it supports, for example, the parameters: `&username=your-user&password=your-pwd&submit=yes` then you can definitely implement it ;)

Comment: @user25502: It may be more realistic to assemble the POST request in a form on your own site. There's no reason that a form on one site can't POST to another site. (Caveat: some sites prevent this sort of cross-site POSTing, by including dynamically-generated field values. But it's still more likely to work than the approach alfasin describes, since that requires explicit support on the part of the site you're logging into.)

Answer (score 1):

You could just trigger a click event on page load:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').click();
});
```

Comment: Interesting...I like that idea.

'#button' would be the applicable login or form submit button?

Comment: That's correct. That is what I am using on: http://www.marandy.com/onlinebooking/login-guest.php - it basically logs in on a 'guest' account and directs it to the booking page

Comment: silly question...how do you determine the value of '#button'?  and thank you btw!

Comment: Well say for example in your HTML you have: `<input type="button" id="element" name="submit" value="submit" />` the selector you would use is `$('#element').click();`. #id selector, .class selector.

Comment: or if you wanting to select it by the name attribute it would be $("[name=submit]") for the above example

Answer (score 0):

No, if you don't have control over the page that you are linking to, you cannot automatically submit a form (or run any scripts) on it.

Any web browser that let you do that would be very insecure (XSS vulnerabilities).

Answer (score 0):

If you have direct control of the page, you can create the following code (using jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myForm').submit();
});
```

If you aren't the owner of the page, and if it doesn't support a GET request like, for example, `https://www.somesite.com/login?user=me&pass=12345` you won't be able to generate the needed URL, but, if you are developing your own page that will have links to the other one that you will try to auto-login, you can simulate links with a form and make the submit button look like an hyperlink, for example:

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.somesite.com/login">

    <input id="user" name="user" value="me" type="hidden" />
    <input id="pass" name="pass" value="12345" type="hidden" />

    <input type="submit" style="... style needed to make it look like an hyperlink ..." />
</form>
```

Obviously you must know the information the Website is expecting to receive when someone clicks their login button. A fast look in their HTML code or tracking the network should be enough.

As a note, currently most of the web sites use, at least, a hidden field with randomly generated values that will try to prevent other websites to generate forms that will post to their website and if that's the case, I believe it's not possible to achieve what you want.